# DIV tag fit into td

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

    <html>
    <head>

    <title>WEB PAGE TITLE GOES HERE</title>

    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',verdana;">

    <table width="100%" style="height: 100%;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>

    <!-- ============ HEADER SECTION ============== -->
    <td colspan="2" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#777d6a"><h1>Website Logo</h1></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <!-- ============ LEFT COLUMN (MENU) ============== -->
    <td width="20%" valign="top" bgcolor="#999f8e">
    <a href="#">Menu link</a><br>
    <a href="#">Menu link</a><br>
    <a href="#">Menu link</a><br>
    <a href="#">Menu link</a><br>
    <a href="#">Menu link</a>
    </td>

    <!-- ============ RIGHT COLUMN (CONTENT) ============== -->
    <td width="80%" valign="top" bgcolor="#d2d8c7">
    <div id='BookIssue_errorloc' class='error_strings' style='width:980px;text-align:left'></div>
              <div id='BookIssue_outer_div' class='form_outer_div' style='width:980px;height:600px'>
              <div style='position:relative' id='BookIssue_inner_div'>
// some form goes here
    </td></tr></table>
    </body>

    <html>
```

The form is fitting but I am getting horizontal and vertical scroll bars . what I want is how to align correctly the form with div tags in td without having scroll bars and no space should be left in x direction and in y direction.

Comment: Don't use table for layout...

Comment: childElement { display:block; }

Comment: Also.. Listen to @Alberto

Comment: Table based layouts are a recipe for disaster. Geocities didn't succeed for a reason. http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/ 

This link will help you get started in the right direction.

Comment: You may also find this flexbox guide useful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/